# MySql multiplication columns with NULL and 0 rows

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have this MySQL table:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
| ID | DESCRIPTION | QUANTITY | EACH | PRICE |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
| 1  | Product 1   |     1    |  12  | 1*12  |
| 2  | Product 2   |     2    |   3  | 2* 3  |
| 3  | Product 3   |   NULL   |   3  |       |
| 4  | Product 4   |     0    |   7  |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
```

And this query:

```
SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  COALESCE(QUANTITY, 1) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1
```

I want to replace NULL and 0 with 1 and I want to make the multiplication in the column PRICE. I don't want to use UPDATE because I can't change the values in the table1.
Thank you!

Comment: Try this : `SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  if(QUANTITY is NULL OR QUANTITY=0,1,QUANTITY) as QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  (if(QUANTITY is NULL OR QUANTITY=0,1,QUANTITY) as QUANTITY) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below query

```
SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  COALESCE(IF(QUANTITY = NULL OR QUANTITY = 0,1,QUANTITY), 1) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1
```

Comment: `QUANTITY = NULL` does not work (at least not the way you expect: it is never true). Use `QUANTITY IS NULL`, then you can remove `COALESCE`.

Comment: We can also use like `QUANTITY IS NULL` way i agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  IF(QUANTITY,QUANTITY, 1) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1
```

> [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ea63/1)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `CASE`:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, EACH,
       ((CASE WHEN QUANTITY IS NULL THEN 0
              WHEN QUANTITY = 0 THEN 1
              ELSE QUANTITY
         END) * EACH
       ) AS PRICE
FROM table1;
```